# An EditText that only allows valid signed decimal numbers to be entered

Tags: android, android-edittext

There are many similar questions, but no adequate solution that works on all keyboards.

I want an EditText that accepts only valid signed decimal numbers to be entered on all common keyboards. I don't want to be able to enter multiple decimal points, or negative sign in the middle of the number so I don't have to catch the exception. Examples of valid signed decimal numbers are 55, -65.43, etc.

Right now this is what I have:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="-0123456789.,"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

I have an `InputFilter` like this:

```
class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter
{

    private final int decimalDigits;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int decimalDigits)
    {
        this.decimalDigits = decimalDigits;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        int dotPos = -1;
        int len = dest.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            char c = dest.charAt(i);
            if (c == '.' || c == ',')
            {
                dotPos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dotPos >= 0)
        {

            // protects against many dots
            if (source.toString().equals(".") || source.toString().equals(","))
            {
                return "";
            }
            // if the text is entered before the dot
            if (dend <= dotPos)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (len - dotPos > decimalDigits)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        if (source.toString().equals("-") && dest.length() > 0)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Which works fine except for certain Samsung keyboards that combine the decimal point and negative sign in one key as below (where the button must be tapped twice to get the negative sign). In that case it doesn't allow the negative sign.

Surely there must be a way to do this correctly?

[image]